# Vue,js Display data from json

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How to fetch the product name from the below result. I tried

```
 <div class="card-divider">
            {{ post.basic_info.prod_name }}
</div>
```

But it is not working

Many thanks

```
     {
     "name":"Test ProductCategory",
     "updated":"2018-07-16 15:00:03",

     "12":{
      "basic_info":{
         "prod_name":"Product name 1",
         "status":"Active",
         "image":""
      },
     },
     "13":{
        "basic_info":{
         "prod_name":"Product name 2",
         "status":"Active",
         "image":""
        },
     }
    }
```

Comment: Show us your script code

Comment: Maybe you don't use v-for here. Show us your code.

Comment: Moreover, you have two keys of the same name `"12":`, your code is not enough to answer!

Comment: methods: {
          getPostsViaREST: function() {
            axios.get("http://localhost/learning-vue-js/data/455.json")
            .then(response => {this.posts = response.data})
        }

Comment: @Zam85 basic_info is inside "12"

Comment: iam using it inside v-for and iam getting {
         "prod_name":"Product name 2",
         "status":"Active",
         "image":""
        }

Comment: @Zam85 post your full code

Comment: I am running this inside  a v-for and iam getting 

       {
             "prod_name":"Product name 1",
             "status":"Active",
             "image":""
               }


 as a result for 

     {{ post.basic_info}}

 How to get 

     {{ post.basic_info.prod_name }}

Comment: @Zam85 you understand my answer right! `{{ post["12"].basic_info.prod_name }}` this gets you the name but you have same key of an object twice

Comment: @Rajan I have changed the key to 13 And i tried this code but i am getting an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'basic_info' of undefined

Comment: @zam85 you there now! I can help if you show me your whole code, You can reach to my personal email  `paneru.rajan@gmail.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
{{ post["12"].basic_info.prod_name }}
```

Your JSON have two same keys, so you will receive `Product name 2` only, because, latter will replace previous key `"12"`

My suggestion, modify data to receive something like:

```
{
    "name":    "Test ProductCategory",
    "updated": "2018-07-16 15:00:03",
    "data":    [
        {
            "basic_info": {
                "prod_name": "Product name 1",
                "status":    "Active",
                "image":     ""
            },
        }, {
            "basic_info": {
                "prod_name": "Product name 2",
                "status":    "Active",
                "image":     ""
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

you can loop over `data` and get `basic_info.prod_name` then your html will be like:

```
<div class="card-divider"  v-for="obj in post.data">
    {{ obj.basic_info.prod_name }}
</div>
```

Comment: @Zam85 Do you get this?